# Fail to read the whole file in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `.txt` file that has more than 5,000 columns like that:

```
item  0  1  2  3  4  5  .....     4888  4999
3791  0  0  0  0  0  1  .....       24    0
112   1  0  0  0  0  0  .....       0     0
```

And I am trying to read it in R:

```
DF <- read.delim("../f.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE, quote = "")
```

But what I got just a data frame with 99 columns:

```
item  X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  ..... X98
3791  0   0   0   0   0   1  .....   0
112   1   0   0   0   0   0  .....   0
```

Do you know why did it happen? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide us your file

Comment: @Paul how can I do that?

Comment: Try reading only the first line to see what actually is reading in

Comment: I just wrote a 5000 column matrix out using `write.table(data.frame(z),file="z.txt",sep="\t")` and it read back in fine using `df = read.delim("z.txt",head=TRUE, sep="\t")`

Comment: @ZICHAOLI upload the file on a file sharing website and then post the link.

Comment: @Paul https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8VLcriTO2A0LWlOczg0RkhzaUE/view?usp=sharing   Can you access it?

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal Same thing happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `read.delim` so I tried reading your file with `read.table` and it works.

```
> DF <- read.table("../f.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE, quote = "")
> ncol(DF)
> 5001
> nrow(DF)
> 4211
> class(DF)
> [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: the result is a `data.frame`.

Comment: But are you using Rstudio? The data frame shown in Environment has indeed 98 coloumns

Comment: no, I'm using the directly the `R console`. `RStudio` truncates your data, because it would be hard to show in the Enviroment 5001 columns. Use `View(DF)` in order visualize your data.

Comment: also your code works fine and reads all your data!

Comment: Thanks, now I got it

Comment: But do you know how to combine X1:X4999 to a vector? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please be more explicit!

Comment: Now I have a 5001 columns: the first one is item_id and the others are all the side information of the item, I want to transfer side information columns to a long vector(1 * 5000) and store it in one column. So the other 5000 columns are also deleted.

Comment: `as.vector(DF[1,-1])` creates a vector containing the side information of the first item.

Comment: Yes, but the index is still there. I want a mathematical vector.